# SSL warnings while using Origin Certificate on my VPS

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, apache, debian

I created Origin Certificate in cloudflare and installed on my Apache on Debian VPS using the guide https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217472077.

My URL is like this: https://socket.mydomain.com/

I am getting warning "There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)." whenever I visit above URL, why? Remember that I am not using old versions of browsers. Tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) as I recommended on [your original question at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634658/ssl-warnings-while-using-origin-certificate-on-my-vps)? What was the result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CloudFlare's Origin CA is working as intended. It's not trusted by browsers. It's only trusted by *CloudFlare's servers*. Its purpose is to secure communications between CloudFlare and your origin, not for general usage.

Reference: [Introducing CloudFlare Origin CA](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/)

If you want a free, publicly trusted certificate, check out [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). (It's a legitimate and widely-used CA.  It's a non-profit founded by the EFF, Mozilla, and several universities and Internet companies.)

Comment: Actually you don't have to go to another website to get a free publicly trusted certificate. Cloudflare itself has this. The OP only has to enable the orange cloud next to his/her DNS record pointing to the VPS. That's it.

Comment: @Anoyz But the origin server needs a trusted certificate -- either from a public CA or from the Origin CA -- in order to secure the connection between Cloudflare and the origin.

Comment: Yes, which cloudflare gives. You can find the option under the menu "Crypto" on cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

The SSL warnings should go away if you turn on Cloudflare's reverse proxy ("orange-cloud" the DNS record that points to your Debian VPS). You will be presented Cloudflare's browser-trusted Edge certificate when you request your URL.

For fully encrypted end-to-end connection, use the "Full (strict)" SSL setting in Cloudflare's Crypto tab. This way connections between end-users and the proxy will use the Edge certificate, and those between the proxy and your Debian VPS will use the Origin certificate.

Reference: [Introducing CloudFlare Origin CA](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/), same page referenced in @matt-nordhoff's answer. Here's an excerpt from that page:

> When pausing CloudFlare or gray-clouding individual zones, be aware that you and your visitors may receive errors in their browsers until you orange-cloud (reverse proxy) them again.